# select all toggle buttons in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, togglebutton

I am trying to select all toggle buttons exactly like checkboxes select all.

I am using bootstrap4-toggle library

This is my ArrayList

```
$scope.checkboxes = [ 
    {name:'check[]', value:"1", label: "This is Item 1", selected : false}, 
    {name:'check[]', value:"2", label: "This is Item 2", selected : false}, 
    {name:'check[]', value:"3", label: "This is Item 3", selected : false}, 
    {name:'check[]', value:"4", label: "This is Item 4", selected : false}
];
```

Select all method

```
    $scope.toggleSelect = function () {
    angular.forEach($scope.checkboxes, function (item) {
        item.selected = event.target.checked;
        console.log( item.selected= event.target.checked);
    });
}
```

View

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelect()" /> Select All
  <br />
  <div ng-repeat="checkbox in checkboxes">
   <input type="checkbox" name="{{checkbox.name}}" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" value="{{checkbox.value}}"
    ng-model="checkbox.selected">
   </div>
```

**In the console, I got true value but the toggle button is not switched on**

Comment: seems like other issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/TjTYWOl95HVn34AB

Comment: I am using bootstrap4-toggle to display the switch button.

Comment: Where is `event` defined in your Select All method?

Comment: event.target.checked get the true value when select all click